# How can I test my .NET site on Firefox ? It loads in IE but when I open it in Firefox it doesnt load the CSS

Tags: .net, css, visual-studio-2008, firefox, cross-browser

Good day,

I'm almost finished with my .net project implementation of a new design. But I'd like to try it with Firefox before releasing it.
When I debug the project it creates an URL with "http://localhost/rest-of-url" and it opens IE and I can see the site. But when I copy this URL to Firefox it won't load the CSS at all. Is that a problem with Visual Studio 2008 ? Or do I have to do something different?
I've got to say I'm a complete .NET newbie I'm just integrating the new design created in xhtml/css into this existing web application.

I'd like to see if I'm gonna be able to try cross browser testing without having to release this to the staging server. It would be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can test in Firefox like that. The localhost url which Visual Studio exposes is usable from any local browser.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to check what URL it's trying to load the CSS from, and to check whether you get any CSS errors.

Comment: I uploaded the site to the staging server and it all looks very nice in all the 4 browsers. But when it is on my computer, I can only see it thru IE.
I do use Firebug. I'm not missing anything. I'm just asking if it is a normal behavior as I'm new to the .net framework. In ten years I haven't used Visual Studio.

Comment: This is not a normal issue.  Check what the server is responding.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may have an error in your css that is causing firefox to not interpret it correctly or at all. IE is more forgiving of these types of errors. Firefox is much more strict to standards.